# Gap-and-island for more than time threshold

Tags: sql, postgresql, gaps-and-islands

I have these tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE labels(user_id INT, session_id INT,
  start_time TIMESTAMP,mode TEXT);

INSERT INTO labels (user_id,session_id,start_time,mode)
VALUES  (48,652,'2016-04-01 00:47:00+01','foot'),
(9,656,'2016-04-01 00:03:39+01','car'),(9,657,'2016-04-01 00:26:51+01','car'),
(9,658,'2016-04-01 00:45:19+01','car'),(46,663,'2016-04-01 00:13:12+01','car');

CREATE TABLE raw_data(user_id INT, session_id INT,timestamp TIMESTAMP) ;

INSERT INTO raw_data(user_id, session_id,timestamp)          
VALUES (8,652,'2016-04-01 00:46:11.638+01'),(8,652,'2016-04-01 00:47:00.566+01'),
       (8,652,'2016-04-01 00:48:06.383+01'),(9,656,'2016-04-01 00:14:17.707+01'),
       (9,656,'2016-04-01 00:15:18.664+01'),(9,656,'2016-04-01 00:16:19.687+01'),
       (9,656,'2016-04-01 00:24:20.691+01'),(9,656,'2016-04-01 00:25:23.681+01'),
       (9,657,'2016-04-01 00:24:50.842+01'),(9,657,'2016-04-01 00:26:51.096+01'),
       (9,657,'2016-04-01 00:37:54.092+01');
```

I want to investigate sessions of a user having time time difference between successive rows greater than 5 minutes, reporting:

- session and session mode
- number of sessions with the gap-and-island problem.

My attempt:

```sql
select session_id     
      ,timestamp    
      ,user_id  
      ,start_time   
      ,count(diff) over()/2 as number_of_session_with_problem
from  (
       select *
              ,case when timestamp-lag(timestamp) over(partition by session_id order by timestamp)    > '00:05:00.000' then 1 when lead(timestamp) over(partition by session_id order by timestamp) - timestamp > '00:05:00.000' then 1 end as diff
       from   raw_data join labels using(session_id)
      ) t
```

Error:

```
ERROR:  column reference "user_id" is ambiguous
LINE 3:       ,user_id 
               ^
```

Expected results:

```
session_id  timestamp            user_id    start_time        number_of_session_with_problem
   656     2016-04-01 00:16:19.687  9      2016-04-01 00:03:39     1
   657     2016-04-01 00:26:51.096  9      2016-04-01 00:26:51     2
```

Note: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UZq0ZVC4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is we have two `user_id` and they're not defined so you need to specifically choose them and give them aliases.

```
select  session_id    
       ,timestamp   
       ,user_id 
       ,start_time  
       ,count(diff) over() as number_of_sessions_with_problem
from   (
       select session_id     
             ,timestamp    
             ,labels.user_id  
             ,start_time   
             ,case when lead(timestamp) over(partition by session_id order by timestamp)-timestamp > '00:05:00.000' then 1 end as diff
       from   raw_data join labels using(session_id)
       ) t
where  diff = 1
```

| session_id | timestamp | user_id | start_time | number_of_sessions_with_problem |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 656 | 2016-04-01 00:16:19.687 | 9 | 2016-04-01 00:03:39 | 2 |
| 657 | 2016-04-01 00:26:51.096 | 9 | 2016-04-01 00:26:51 | 2 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/I8lCrgNJ)